# Why we should avoid two multiple traces instead of one trace while take power trace?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I am new to PCB design and I am working on  8 layer board, which consist Ethernet and audio signals. In this design we are using routing instead of power plane shaped on power filters ( 500mA and 1A) .first we take multiple traces from power pin due to lack of space in BGA room then customer asked us to take routing wide trace rather than two trace?
Here my question is a.  What is the impact if we take two traces other than bga room issue (DFM)
b.  We are taking two traces equal to a single wide trace, is there any PI issue if we take two thin traces?

Comment: Because 5 + 5 < 15.

Comment: Somebody needs to go back to elementary school and learn their basic arithmetic....

Comment: @susen Why would that matter? If the customer wants it then give them what they want, its good business practice. Maybe they want the same voltage at both their loads. In general running two small traces is bad, it increases parasitics. You would have to tell us what the loads are for this question to be meaningful

Answer (score 3):

Lets just say you split the 15mil trace into two 7.5mil traces. Most manufacturers will need a 5-7mil spacing between traces, so instead of 15mil of width, you have 20-22mil. You just made routing more complicated and use more area for no reason.

It might make sense to run two separate traces to different loads if you worried about source resistance OR a kelvin connection.